# Finder not seeing my UTI

Tags: macos, macos-carbon, uti

I'm trying to tell OSX's Finder that my email client application can open .eml files and so far it's not going so well. I took a leaf from Mail.app's plist and pretty much copied most of the UTI values straight over, just changing the UTTypeIdentifier to my own company.

The plist as it stands:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.memecode.scribe.email</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Email.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Email Message</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Email.icns</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.email-message</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Email Message</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.memecode.scribe.email</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>eml</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>message/rfc822</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Mail is declaring a UTI for the .eml extension, I don't think it makes sense to define your own UTI for the same extension.  Just use Mail's UTI under LSItemContentTypes.  If you want, you could copy Mail's UTI declaration as an imported type.

Comment: Indeed, you *need* to import Mail's UTI declaration into your own Info.plist, and then use Mail's UTI rather than your own in `CFBundleDocumentTypes`. I wrote an app awhile back to help with both of those: http://boredzo.org/uti-plist-helper/

Comment: This works, but I wonder what happens if Mail.app is deleted on the host system? Seems like I'm depending on Mail.app to be there and working ok, which I find unsettling. I'd prefer to be totally independent of Mail.app. (Currently I'm importing their UTI... which makes my app appear on the "open with" menu for .eml files)

Comment: @fret: It's fine if Mail.app is deleted.  That's really the point of writing an imported declaration.  You're saying, I don't own this UTI, but just in case the owner isn't around, here's the declaration.